# There are 5 blue socks, 4 red socks and 3 green socks in Debu's wardrobe. He has to select 4 socks from this set. In how many ways can he do so?

Tags: combinations

Total number of socks = 5+4+3 = 12
4 to be selected
So number of ways of selecting = 12$C$4 = 495 ways

Is this correct?

Comment: This is correct if the socks are distinguishable. However, if you consider selecting any 4 blue socks to be one "way" (regardless of precisely which 4 blue socks you chose), then the answer will be different.

Comment: No, that can't be correct.  If it were correct, the whole point of designating that some of the socks are blue, some are green, some are red would become meaningless.  The only way that the question makes sense is to assume that all socks of the same color are **indistinguishable** from each other.

Comment: That is correct assuming that he can tell the difference between each of the blue socks... that there is a "first" blue sock and a "second" blue sock etc...  If all he cares about is the quantity of each color sock and doesn't care about specifically *which* of each type of sock it was... then this is incorrect.

Comment: Since the numbers involved are so small, I suggest forgoing any attempt at elegance, and considering the following $5$ cases: $k$ blue socks are selected, where $k \in \{0,1,2,3,4\}.$  For each case, you may have subcases to manually enumerate.

Answer (score 1):

There are so few cases that we can just list artistically in the order blue-red-green in descending numbers

$\displaylines {400\\310\; 301\\220\; 211\; 202\\130\;121\;112\;103\\040\;031\;022\;013}$

Comment: Amazing approach. Thank You

Comment: Glad you like it :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could have used $^{12}C_4$ if all items were different, now now.

Now, you can have the following cases.

**Case I:** All $4$ socks of the same color. $2$ ways. (either blue or red)

**Case II:** $3$ socks of the same color, $4$th of the different color. $^3C_1\times^2C_1=6$ ways.

**Case III:** $2$ socks of one color. Other $2$ of other color. i.e. we are picking $2$ colors from which $2$-$2$ socks each would be picked. $^3C_2=3$ ways.

**Case IV:**  $2$ socks of one color. Other $2$ of two other colors. $^3C_1=3$ ways.

Total$=2+6+3+3=14$ ways.

Comment: Ohh that's right.... Thank You so much!

Answer (score 0):

This is a Stars and Bars problem, which is discussed [here](https://brilliant.org/wiki/integer-equations-star-and-bars/) and
[here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).

Let $x_1, x_2, x_3$ denote the number of blue, red, and green socks selected, respectively.

The number of non-negative integer solutions to 
$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 4$

is $~\displaystyle \binom{4 + 2}{2} = \binom{6}{2} = 15.$

The only possible violation to the constraint that 
$x_1 \leq 5, ~x_2 \leq 4, ~x_3 \leq 3$ 
is $(x_1,x_2,x_3) = (0,0,4).$

Therefore, the overall enumeration is $15 - 1 = 14.$